# How to find value of a cell from named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is in EXCEL some formala, that can find value of a cell. Something like INDEX, but instead of an index column, a named range.

I want to find cell in this named range and i know index of row

Comment: You need to supply more detail - You have a named range...but which cell to you want to find - please give an example showing required results

Comment: I want to find cell in this named range and i know index of row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `INDEX` as you would normally, and specifiy the name rather than the range, eg if `YourNamedRange` names the range `A1:A100` then

```
=INDEX(YourNamedRange, IndexNumber)
```

and

```
=INDEX(A1:A100, IndexNumber)
```

are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

for vba
range("YourNamedRange").cells(1,1)
will get you the value of the first cell in the range