# Perform Lookup that return nearest value

Tags: excel, excel-2013

In excel, assuming I have two columns of data:

```
Column A:
-10
0
10

Column B:
Ugly
OK
Pretty
```

I try to vlookup a value between -9 and -1 from column A and it will return "Ugly". How do I make it return "OK"? Same goes value of 1 to 9, I want excel to return me "Pretty". I try to find Index Match method but couldn't find one with simple example like this.

Bonus question: If I "name" A1:B3 as "DogRating", how do I use this name in formula so that it refers to "Pretty" - i.e. DogRating(2,3) usually in array? That doesn't work in excel.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the formula you have used??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use 10,0,1 as your indices, you can achieve your result by using the below formula

```
Column A:
-10
0
1

Column B:
Ugly
OK
Pretty

=VLOOKUP(F1,DogRating,2,TRUE)
```

DogRating is `A1:B3`

`F1` is user input

`TRUE` is used for Approximate match

**Results:**

```
-10 to -1 => Ugly
0 => OK
1 to 10 => Pretty
```

BTW, for values higher than 10 also the result is pretty

Answer (score 0):

Agree with nighcrawler. The behavior of VLOOKUP is well-defined here as requiring the lookup table indicies to appear in ASCENDING order, where the results for a range lookup will always be BELOW your lookup value:
http://www.excelfunctions.net/Vlookup-Example-Closest-Match.html

Regarding your bonus question, you could use the Index function, as shown here:
[How to find value of a cell from named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475585/how-to-find-value-of-a-cell-from-named-range)

Answer (score 0):

Place the value in **C1**, then in another cell enter the *array formula*:

```
=INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A3-C1)),ABS(A1:A3-C1),0))
```

For example:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The formula finds the value in column **A** closest to the value in **C1** and returns the adjacent value in column **B**. *(this formula does not require the table to be sorted.)*